# Alter column with default constraint in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

This works fine in SQL Server.

```
ALTER TABLE HS_HR_PEA_EMPLOYEE
ADD CONSTRAINT SET_ADDED_TIME_AUTOMATICALLY DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR JS_PICKED_TIME
```

What is the Oracle equivalent query for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add DEFAULT current date for your column

```
ALTER TABLE HS_HR_PEA_EMPLOYEE MODIFY JS_PICKED_TIME DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
```